# How can I selectively render code in a Create React App SPA?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, craco

In my React app (built with Create React App cli, and not ejected) I have it set up so if there is no `REACT_APP_API_URL` defined then it uses mocked data.

I do this by suppling a `fakeFetch` function to [`redux-api-middleware`](https://github.com/agraboso/redux-api-middleware#fetch) ala

```js
import { apiMiddleware as aMl, createMiddleware } from 'redux-api-middleware'
import fakeFetch from 'fixtures/utils/fakeFetch'

const apiMiddleware = apiBase ? aMl : createMiddleware({ fetch: fakeFetch })

// etc... configure the `redux` store with the middleware
```

That's fine when developing, but I'd like for that code to be completely detached from the build when actually building for deployment.

Is there any way I can do something along the lines of

```js
<% if process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL %>
import { apiMiddleware } from 'redux-api-middleware'
<% else %>
import { createMiddleware } from 'redux-api-middleware'
import fakeFetch from 'fixtures/utils/fakeFetch'

const apiMiddleware = createMiddleware({ fetch: fakeFetch })
<% endif %>

// etc... configure the `redux` store with the middleware
```

to prevent `webpack` from including up all my fixtures / fake data in the production build, while giving me a very simple way to switch between mock vs live data?

I do not want to have to eject the app, but am open to using a webpack plugin that's injected using [Create React App Configuration Overrides](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco).

Comment: Does this article answer your question? https://remarkablemark.org/blog/2017/02/25/webpack-ignore-module/


(Edit: Nvm, it involves a custom webpack configuration which would involve ejecting)

Comment: I have used https://github.com/pofigizm/redux-dynamic-middlewares for a similar use case in my application.

Comment: Thanks @AbirTaheer but that solution doesn't fully help me.  It's not enough to just selectively ignore a module based on a regex.

Comment: Can you not just read `process.env.NODE_ENV` and check if you're in development versus production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [webpack code-splitting](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/) with [dynamic imports](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports) could be your best bet. This way, your mock data is bundled but never sent to the client (which I think is the main goal here).

```
import { apiMiddleware, createMiddleware } from 'redux-api-middleware'

const getMiddleware = async () => {
   if (process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL) {
      return apiMiddleware;
   } else {
      // loads bundle over network
      const { default: fakeFetch } = await import('fixtures/utils/fakeFetch');
      return createMiddleware({ fetch: fakeFetch });
   }
}
```

I know this does not answer the question directly but on a side note, I think the cleanest way would be to utilise a mock sever such as [mock-server.com](https://www.mock-server.com/). In development, you would just use the mock server url in `process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL`. This way, the test data lives in a completely different environment and provide a clear separation of concerns. You could probably also just create a simple local express app that just returns hardcoded JSON if you don't want to use third-party tools.

Comment: this is very close to how I've eventually solved this, so I've awarded the bounty - thanks.  I have a number of reasons for not wanting to add a mock server (the simulations of the API in my fake API are fairly complex and rely on the same quite complex sets of fixture data I use in unit tests, so it was easiest to keep to all together). I've got it working now so thanks.